# ¿Como escribo el simbolo "¿" en Python 2.7?

Tags: python

¿Como se puede escribir el símbolo "¿" en una cadena de texto manejable en Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

Añade las siguientes líneas al principio del fichero para poder utilizar UTF-8 en cadenas y comentarios:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar la codificacion en las primeras lineas, para el caso la codifcacion seria utf-8. El siguiente ejemplo imprimira el estring “¿Como va todo con Python?".

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
texto = "¿Como va todo con Python?"
print texto
```

Espero haberte ayudado, Saludos.